# why can't I instialize the struct member fields separately?! (In USB device driver)

Tags: drivers, usb, usb-drive

I'm trying to implement usb device driver. I've wrote

```
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/usb.h>
struct usb_device_id IDtable[]={  
{USB_DEVICE(0x067b,0x2303)},
{}
};
int ttlprobe(struct usb_interface *interface, const struct usb_device_id *id)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Probed (%04X:%04X) device\n", id->idVendor, id->idProduct);
    printk(KERN_INFO "num_altsetting :  %d\n",interface->num_altsetting);
    return 0;
}
void ttldisconnect(struct usb_interface *interface)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Device disconnected \n");
}

struct usb_driver busb;
busb.name="guru";
busb.id_table=IDtable;
busb.probe=ttlprobe(&busb,IDtable);
busb.disconnect=ttldisconnect;

int init_module(void){
printk(KERN_ALERT "intimodule exec Trying to register to USB CORE \n");
int k=usb_register(&busb); 
printk(KERN_INFO "retuern value of usb_register_driver : %d\n",k);
pr_info("name    = %s\n", THIS_MODULE->name);
pr_info("name    = %s\n", KBUILD_MODNAME);
return k;
}

void cleanup_module(void){
printk(KERN_ALERT "Trying to de-register to USB CORE");
return usb_deregister(&busb);
}
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Anil Kumar Pugalia <email_at_sarika-pugs_dot_com>");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("USB Pen Registration Driver");
```

**and output was this,**

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.10.0-28-generic/build M=/home/guru/Desktop/Linuxx/Drivers/USB/check modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-28-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/guru/Desktop/Linuxx/Drivers/USB/check/chc.o
/home/guru/Desktop/Linuxx/Drivers/USB/check/chc.c:20:5: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘.’ token
 busb.name="guru";
     ^
/home/guru/Desktop/Linuxx/Drivers/USB/check/chc.c:21:5: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘.’ token
 busb.id_table=IDtable;
     ^
/home/guru/Desktop/Linuxx/Drivers/USB/check/chc.c:22:5: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘.’ token
 busb.probe=ttlprobe(&busb,IDtable);
     ^
/home/guru/Desktop/Linuxx/Drivers/USB/check/chc.c:23:5: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘.’ token
 busb.disconnect=ttldisconnect;
     ^
/home/guru/Desktop/Linuxx/Drivers/USB/check/chc.c: In function ‘init_module’:
/home/guru/Desktop/Linuxx/Drivers/USB/check/chc.c:27:1: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
 int k=usb_register(&busb); 
 ^
scripts/Makefile.build:301: recipe for target '/home/guru/Desktop/Linuxx/Drivers/USB/check/chc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/guru/Desktop/Linuxx/Drivers/USB/check/chc.o] Error 1
Makefile:1524: recipe for target '_module_/home/guru/Desktop/Linuxx/Drivers/USB/check' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/guru/Desktop/Linuxx/Drivers/USB/check] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-28-generic'
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**while this one works,**

```
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/usb.h>

struct usb_device_id IDtable[]={  // Defined in "/include/linux/mod_devicetable.h" which is *included* into "linux/usb.h"
{USB_DEVICE(0x067b,0x2303)},
{}
};

int ttlprobe(struct usb_interface *interface, const struct usb_device_id *id)
{
 printk(KERN_INFO "Probed (%04X:%04X) device\n", id->idVendor, id->idProduct);
printk(KERN_INFO "num_altsetting :  %d\n",interface->num_altsetting);


return 0;
}
void ttldisconnect(struct usb_interface *interface)
{
printk(KERN_INFO "Device disconnected \n");
}

struct usb_driver DetectingUSB={        // Defined in /include/linux/usb.h
.name="USBtoTTL",
.id_table=IDtable,
.probe=ttlprobe, 
.disconnect=ttldisconnect,
};


int init_module(void){
printk(KERN_ALERT "intimodule exec Trying to register to USB CORE \n");
int k=usb_register(&DetectingUSB); 


printk(KERN_INFO "retuern value of usb_register_driver : %d\n",k);
pr_info("name    = %s\n", THIS_MODULE->name);
pr_info("name    = %s\n", KBUILD_MODNAME);
return k;
}

void cleanup_module(void){
printk(KERN_ALERT "Trying to de-register to USB CORE");
return usb_deregister(&DetectingUSB);
}
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Why I can't initialize the member fields separately?!

Comment: I don't think any of the Stack sites will thank you for [posting pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Comment: Please post text as text, so that all can read. (Blind people, robots, me, etc)

Comment: Now at least the question is readable, but it's a question about C, not about Linux. The answer from Stephen Kitt already explains, you can’t initialise field members outside a of function, or more general, you can't put code outside a of function. Your further comment shows lack of understanding of the general concepts. Why would you want to have your initialization code outside `init_module`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t initialise field members in this fashion outside a function. If you really want to do this, you’d need to move the initialisation code inside the `init_module` function.

Note too that your

```
busb.probe=ttlprobe(&busb,IDtable);
```

would assign the result of `ttlprobe(&busb, IDtable)` to `probe`, rather than a pointer to the function which is what is expected.

Use the initialisation block, that’s what is expected here.

Comment: Thanks fella. I've tried and it worked out. But mine only concern is why can't I initialize the member fields outside init_module?!!